# Rebind C-x b to ivy-switch-buffer

Tags: key-bindings

I find ivy-switch-to-buffer is handy [abo-abo/swiper: Ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper)

[image]

Is it possible to bind the function to C-x b

Additionally, my C-x C-b is bonded to ibuffer

How could rebind it to function 'helm-buffer-list"?

[image]

Comment: You'll want to add something like this to your init file: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") #'helm-buffer-list)` I don't know which function in `swiper` you're talking about, and I can't quickly find it in the source, so you'll have to figure that one out yourself. It's weird that there are no questions about binding keys to commands here.

Comment: Please take a look at the manual on binding keys.

Comment: Or just activate ivy-mode